# Running Second Setup Disk from Flashdrive

Tags: installation, usb-flash-drive

I'm trying to install Soldier of Fortune II Double Helix on my laptop (out of nostalgia), but since my laptop doesn't have a CD drive I had to copy the 2 disk folders onto a flash drive and am installing the game that way. Unfortunately I don't know how to run the second disk when I get the "Please insert disk 2" message.

In the folder for the second disk, there is an AUTORUN application type and a Setup application type but neither activate the continued installation of the game.

What are my options?

Comment: I am not sure what ISOs and mounting are in terms of CDs

Comment: You can find lots of information regarding the suggested method in old gamers' forums because it was the preferred way to pirate games some 10-15 years ago.